# Understanding how pipelines work in Bash: cat | cat | ls pipeline hangs until two inputs are provided

Tags: c, bash, shell, command-line, pipe

I'm trying to understand how pipelines work in Bash, but I'm having trouble with a specific command: cat | cat | ls. According to my understanding, the first cat command should write its output to the first pipe, the second cat command should read from the first pipe and write its output to the second pipe, and the ls command should read from the second pipe and list the files in the current directory. However, when I run this command, it seems to hang until I provide two inputs. I'm confused about why this is happening and whether the cat commands are reading from standard input or from the pipes. Can someone help me understand what's going on here?

I tried running the cat | cat | ls command in Bash, expecting the first cat command to write its output to the first pipe, the second cat command to read from the first pipe and write its output to the second pipe, and the ls command to read from the second pipe and list the files in the current directory. However, when I ran this command, it seemed to hang until I provided two inputs. I'm not sure why this is happening and whether the cat commands are reading from standard input or from the pipes.

Comment: `ls` does _not_ read from `stdin`, so piping _to_ it does nothing. You might have better luck with: `ls | cat | cat`

Comment: Also, piping through `cat` multiple times will tell you more about your version of `cat` (specifically, its buffering behavior) than it does about pipes.

Comment: re: "whether the cat commands are reading from standard input or from the pipes."  Both cat processes are reading from their stdin.  For one, stdin is inherited from the shell that spawns the pipeline (eg, your keyboard), for the other, it is the pipe.  IOW, stdin *is* the pipe, and you are making an artificial distinction.

Comment: What do you mean by "provided two inputs"?  The second `cat` won't terminate until it tries to write to the standard input of `ls` after `ls` has exited; and it can't write anything until the first `cat` sends it some data.  And AFAIK Bash waits for all the processes in the pipeline to finish before continuing.  The only question then is why it takes two lines of input to the first `cat` to get the second `cat` to try writing.  Blank lines are adequate to trigger the behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

> According to my understanding, the first cat command should write its output to the first pipe, the second cat command should read from the first pipe and write its output to the second pipe,

Yup

> and the ls command should read from the second pipe and list the files in the current directory.

It would have, but `ls` happens not to read any input. It just list the files in the current directory and immediately exits.

> However, when I run this command, it seems to hang until I provide two inputs.

This happens because of how pipeline closures propagate backwards.

A pipe has a read end and a write end. If you close the read end and then try to write to the write end, you get a SIGPIPE which by default will terminate the current process.

In your case, `ls` has listed the directory and exited, closing all its FDs including the read end of the second pipe.

When you enter your first input, the first `cat` reads it and successfully writes it to the first pipe. The second cat reads it, and tries to write to the second pipe. However, since the second pipe has a closed read end, the `cat` receives a SIGPIPE during the `write` and dies, closing all its open FDs.

Then you enter your second input. The first `cat` reads it, and tries to write it to the second pipe. However, since the read end is closed, it results in another SIGPIPE and the first `cat` dies.

Since all three commands have exited, the pipeline is done.

If you had used `cat | cat | cat | ls` then you would similarly see you need 3 inputs, one for each `cat` to realize that its downstream pipe has closed.

If you had used `cat | cat | sleep 10`, you can see that you can enter as much text as you want for 10 seconds (at least up to ~65k or whatever your OS pipe buffer is), and then it again takes two inputs after the `sleep` has exited.

Answer (score 1):

**TLDR**: Your cat pipeline is working, it's just not doing what you think it should.

There were really a couple of questions buried in there:

1. Why doesn't `cat | cat | ls` work?
2. Why does it "hang until I provide two inputs"?
3. How do pipes work?

To answer them, we really need to tackle a few concepts: how `cat` works, how `ls` works, how pipelines (and redirection) work.

## The Answer

Disclaimer: Since the question "why doesn't this work?" has already been (mostly) answered in the comments for the OP, this part will be a lot repeating what has already been said.

As Craig says, while `cat` can take input from stdin (fd 1) or any file descriptor, `ls` takes no input from stdin. `ls`, instead processes arguments and isn't connected to the stdin file descriptor to which the pipe from the last `cat` is writing. Instead, the last pipe connects to the stdin for `ls` ... which doesn't go anywhere. `ls` doesn't even care that you tried to pipe anything to it. It executes as normal.

For example, if we remove the `ls` and give `cat` something meaningful, the `cat | cat` pipe works like I think you'd expect:

```
$ echo "hello" | cat | cat
hello
```

However, if we add the pipe into `ls` at the end, we get nothing (not even an error). This is because Bash successfully piped the output to stdin for `ls` - but then `ls` doesn't do anything with it. The need for the "two inputs" goes away, however, since we are giving `cat` an actual input (NOTE: I'm redirecting stderr to stdin to show no error, though this isn't necessary on this terminal):

```
$ echo "hello" | cat | cat | ls 2&>1
ans.md
```

So the "answer" to your first two questions:

1. Why doesn't `cat | cat | ls` work?: It does work, it's just not doing what you probably want.
2. Why does it "hang until I provide two inputs"?: As Jonathan said (and what William alluded to), the first `cat` in the pipeline is waiting for its first input, which you provide with the "second" input.

## The Much Better Answer

This part is why I decided to actually answer this question in so many words. In Bash, pipelines and redirection (different, but pretty similar things) are IMO the coolest features. For real, they're the coolest. Do you have a moment to hear about our shell lord and savior Bash redirection? Well I'm gonna talk about it anyway. Let's proceed to talk all about it ...

First, on [redirection](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html) (*sparkle sparkle*). In Bash, any file IO and any stdin, stdout, or stderr is treated basically as an open file - called a "file descriptor". From GNU on [Redirections](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html):

> Before a command is executed, its input and output may be redirected using a special notation interpreted by the shell. Redirection allows commands’ file handles to be duplicated, opened, closed, made to refer to different files, and can change the files the command reads from and writes to.

Next, on pipes (*sparkle sparkle sparkle*). [Pipelines](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pipelines.html) are not actually redirections since they don't redirect input or output to or from any file descriptor to another. Instead they "pipe" the stdout of one command to the stdin of the next command in the pipe. Again, let us refer to the GNU holy book:

> A pipeline is a sequence of one or more commands separated by one of the control operators ‘|’ or ‘|&’.
>
> The format for a pipeline is
>
> [time [-p]] [!] command1 [ | or |& command2 ] …
>
> The output of each command in the pipeline is connected via a pipe to the input of the next command. That is, each command reads the previous command’s output. This connection is performed before any redirections specified by `command1`.

To reiterate a tiny detail, **this connection is performed before any redirections specified by `command1`**. It's a pretty important detail that can be lost. What this means is that while redirection can change what the specified file descriptor points to, it doesn't change the file descriptions themselves and the pipe will always refer to the file description for stdout. E.g. if we redirect stdout to point to `/dev/null` (by writing `> /dev/null`), we are changing our file descriptor to point at null, but a subsequent pipe is still reading from the file description for stdout so, as a result, no data will be sent over the pipe.

I should also briefly point out that while the data can be rerouted though pipes or redirected at your whim, the format of the data could be modified a bit (things like tabs and newlines often show up differently). Just something to keep in mind.

So now back to the original expression, [`cat`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cat.1.html) can read from stdin or from a file while [`ls`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ls.1.html) simply reads input arguments. So, while we can use pipes and redirection into and out of `cat`, only stdout can be usefully piped out of `ls`, since that's all it has. We can use [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html) to supply arguments (e.g. `ls ${cat alistofdirs.txt`) ... but that's a little off topic I guess? So let's rearrange things in the original expression to actually do some stuff using only pipes:

```
$ ls | cat | cat
ans.md
```

(`ans.md` is this answer file, BTW. It's all I have in the directory I'm testing this from)

So that's cool. All we did here is move the `ls` to the start of the pipeline so that the output of `ls` is piped to `cat`, then to the next `cat`, which then just prints the results of the `ls`. Not very exciting. Can we do more? Great question. The answer is of course yes. How about adding some cool redirection?

```
$ cat <(ls) | cat
ans.md
```

Oh yea. That's good. We moved the `ls` into a [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html) expression (another kind of redirection) to make it look like a file, then used `cat` on the "file" and piped the result to another `cat`. Very nice... But can we do more?

```
$ exec 3< <(cat <(ls)); cat <&3; exec 3>&-
ans.md
```

Ohhhh yea. Take a minute to soak this nonsense into your soul. I mean, just look at that thing. What a monstrosity. We are still using process substitution to `cat` the result of `ls`, but now we are redirecting that output to a new file descriptor 3 (via another process substitution) and then using `cat` on the new file descriptor (and finally closing the file descriptor 3) .. How totally and amazingly useless .... But can we do more?

```
$ ((cat 3>&1 <((((cat >&4 <<< cat <(ls)) 4>&5) 5>&1 4>&- | cat >&6 5>&-) 6>&1) 3>&1 6>&-) 3>&- | tee /dev/fd/7 1> /dev/null) 2> /dev/null 7>&1 | cat
ans.md
```

Behold, the most complicated and obfuscated `ls` invocation I've ever conceived. TBH, I'm not 100% sure the command above is doing exactly what I think it should. I constructed the thing as carefully as I could but ... you know. Anyway, you get the point. I tried to fit in every redirection concept I know of in there, some of which do nothing and some of them do something.

## Conclusion

So what was the point of all this? My point here was that while "cat" and "ls" (and just about everything else) have restrictions on what kind of input and output they support, that is pretty easy to work around in bash. Clearly you can do all kinds of weirdness to make any input look like any other kind of output, so those limitations aren't really that big of a deal. Also, I just think redirections are super fun to think about and work with and I took the question as an opportunity to write a big long post about something useless.

I would also recommend checking out [this advanced bash resource](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/) - the section on redirections in particular (gotta check out the example in the appendix, it's the best)!

... Just make sure not to call something dangerous like this:

```
exec 0> /dev/null
```

Comment: I strongly advise against the "Advanced" bash guide -- the #bash IRC channel spent decades trying to get people to unlearn bad habits it propagates; we ended up writing the [BashGuide](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide) and [BashFAQ](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ) to provide a more trustworthy and actively updated alternative.

Answer (score -1):

***EDIT**: this is **wrong**, not editing it so anyone reading it later can understand the full discussion, especially how I was trying to figure out why we'd have 2 consecutive user inputs ;)*

So, if I got this right on `cat1 | cat2 | ls` :

- `ls` is launched first, because it does not need stdin, and its output *is* possible. This is why it's shown first in bash;
- neither `cat1` nor `cat2` can proceed, because both are still blocked commands (they either don't have input yet, or even can't output too);
- when user insert anything, `cat2` is launched, because it now has an input and also does not need to worry about it's output (fd is probably closed now since `ls` is terminated)
- the last command `cat1` is finally asking for it's own input, and for the same reason as before (its output is now unblocked), as soon as the user type anything the command will be able to launch.
- the reason we do not see anything on the terminal is because for both commands (`cat1` and `cat2`), their output were piped to something else than the usual stdout. So they are launched but we just won't see anything.

Is this what's happening or am I totally off **?** would love to get it right since I'm trying to make a recursive pipeline function and have a hard time understanding how to close the correct fd for it to work as expected! :) Thks

Comment: All three programs in the pipeline are launched at the same time, effectively. (The actual order is implementation-defined and makes no difference to execution: a FIFO hangs when both sides aren't hooked up). It's absolutely untrue that input availability makes any difference to the order of the execv calls.

Comment: Well then, I have the exact same confusion as the OP I guess.

Then why is cat2 not taking it's input from cat1 since they have been piped together. It should only ask for user input once, and the pipeline 'cat1' | 'cat2' could be launched ('ls' is already terminated long time).

Comment: `cat2` **does** have its stdin connected to the stdout of `cat1`; anything the OP insinuated to the contrary is simply wrong. (Whereas while `ls` has its stdin wired to the stdout of `cat2`, `ls` _doesn't care about that at all_, and it proceeds to run a file listing and exit without ever interacting with its stdin in any way; this means that when cat2 tries to write to stdout it'll get an EPIPE -- but of course, it won't have anything to write until it's received content on stdin, and _that_ won't happen until after `cat1` has received content on stdin).

Comment: ...what _can_ happen earlier than an EPIPE is a SIGPIPE affirmatively notifying a process that the other end of the FIFO it's trying to interact with has disconnected. The easy way to check which route is taken in practice is something like `strace -f -o pipeline.strace sh -c 'cat | cat | ls'` to actually get a  logfile showing what really happened during execution (assuming the host OS is Linux).

Comment: (As edited, this still refers to things being "launched" only after input is available; the distinction between when something is executed and when input/output operations _that it invoked after being successfully started_ stop being blocked is a critical one -- when reading the `strace` log from the command I show above, the _actual execution_ is an `execve` call;  you'll see that happens early for all three commands).

Comment: Charles. I really appreciate the time you spent explaining. Thank you!

I might just understood what's going on. The EPIPE and SIGPIPE just explained a lot.
Also, 'that other guy' answer really just lifted what was my sticking point I believe.

Thanks a lot to both of you.